# How to detect if Javascript is running in an cross-domain IFrame in Opera?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, opera

How to detect if JavaScript is running in an cross-domain IFrame in Opera?
If I try to test `if(typeof iframe.parent.document === 'undefined')` Opera 12 just seems to give "Unhandled Error: `Security error: attempted to read protected`" which cannot be caught in code thus breaking execution.

Comment: It should be catchable. Can you give some example page where it isn't getting caught?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. However if your objective is to prevent someone on a different domain from embedding your page in an iframe, there is a http header you can send to prevent this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

It's supported by most modern browsers. It allows you to specify which sites are allowed to embed your page in an iframe.